# Periodic python thread that can be asynchronously poked into action

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-3.x

Making a thread that does something periodically is as simple as setting it's `target` to a function that looks something like:

```
minute = 60
nextTime = time.time()
while True:
    Do_Some_Stuff()
    nextTime += minute
    sleep_time = nextTime - time.time()
    if sleep_time > 0:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

But... what if I want the ability for another thread to poke into action before the period is expired in some cases?

I came up with the following:

```
Trigger = threading.Condition()

def loop():
    while True:
        Do_Some_Stuff()
        with Trigger:
            Trigger.wait(timeout=60)
```

If I launch a `Thread` with `loop` as it's `target`, it will run once a minute, unless I execute a

```
Trigger.notify()
```

from elsewhere. And then it runs right away. Is there a better way to do this? I played with both a `Semaphore` and `Event` implementations, but they both took off once I poked them asynchronously.

And what definitely eludes me, is how I might not just poke it, but poke it at some future point. IOW, whatever your current wait, I'd like the next one to be 5 seconds from now (I guess I could fork another short lived thread that delayed 5 seconds and then drove the Trigger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd at least share what I came up with. I used a `Queue` from the `queue` module. Here's some example code (meant to be run interactively):

```
import threading
import queue
import datetime
import time

Trigger = queue.Queue()

def periodicAction():
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now()) # arbitrary action
        try:
        delta = Trigger.get(timeout=20)
        if delta is not None:
            time.sleep(delta)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

loop = threading.Thread(target=periodicAction)
loop.start()

#now dance with the user
while True:
    response = input('Wakeup how soon? (Enter for immediate)')
    try:
        delta = float(response)
    except ValueError:
        delta = None
    Trigger.put(delta)
```